# I am trying to create widget in next.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

My website is almost complete on next.js. I am trying to create widget to one of my component that can be embedded on any website without iframe. Please help me out

Comment: _What have you tried so far?_ Read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a Web Component Framework

First understand what web components are.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

**recommended frameworks**

- https://stenciljs.com/docs/introduction (made by Ionic)
- https://github.com/github/catalyst (made by Github)
- https://lit.dev/ (made by Google)

Your website being in next.js would not be a factor here. You should build your web component then serve it via CDN or via static folder in next.js. You could reuse your REST routes or styles etc. but you would want a proper modern web component.